# Iterate through a range in bash

Tags: linux, bash, function, for-loop, range

I am trying to create a script that nmap's trough some of our networks in order to find active hosts and hostnames and to fill our IPAM correctly.
I've written a function in Bash that works like a 'subnet calculator' and gives me the exact range that I want to loop through.

The input csv consists of the following information:

```
vlanId;vlanName,Network
1;localLan;192.168.1.0/24;;;
```

Note that the input the function gets is just the network without netmask "`192.168.1.0`"

```
function calculateNet () {
        splitRow=$(echo $1 | sed -e 's/\// /g'| awk '{print $1}')
        netStart=${splitRow: -2}
        if [[ $netStart =~ "." ]] ; then
                netStart=${splitRow: -1}
        fi
        netEnd=$(expr $netStart + $2)
        echo "$netStart..$netEnd"
}

inFile="input/file.csv"
for row in `cat $inFile | sed -e 's/;/ /'g | awk '{print $3}' | egrep ^1`; do
        netSuffix=$(echo $row | sed -e 's/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1,$2,$3'} | sed -e 's/ /./g')
        outFile="output/$netSuffix.csv"
        if [[ $row =~ "/24" ]]; then
                addrCount=254
        elif [[ $row =~ "/26" ]]; then
                addrCount=64
        fi

        range=$(calculateNet $row $addrCount)

        for host in {$range};
        do
                echo $netSuffix.$host
        done
done
```

The function works perfectly, it gives me the correct range to loop through, for a /24 network the result is 0..254.
for a specific /26 network this an be 0..62/64..126/.....

However the `for host in {$range}` does not work. It does not loop through all numbers in the range but outputs it as a string:
`192.168.1.{0..254}`

Why is it nog looping through my range, what am I missing here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Brace expansion happens before variable expansion.

Comment: You could separate the endpoints with space and pass them to the `seq` command, or split them out and use a `for ((host=start; host<=end; host++)); do` loop. BTW, I'd also recommend running your script through [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net).